# PHP/mysql get number of affected rows of UPDATE statement

Tags: php, mysql

With php/mysql how can i get the number of rows that a query affected?

what i tried so far:

```
$result = mysql_query($q);
mysql_num_rows($result);
```

but it says that 
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Comment: @AllisonC you should post that as an answer.. :)

Comment: The warning indicates that the query failed rather than that you are using the wrong function. You should implement proper error handling.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if you're using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (wich i would recommend), for a direct query [`exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) returns the number of affected rows. for [Prepared Statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) theres a method called [`rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

if you're using [the mysql-functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php), there's [`mysql_affected_rows()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php).

**EDIT:**
seems like you're using the mysql-functions. [`mysql_num_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php), wich is what you're using, returns the length of your result set (for SELECT-Statements for example). what you need to use is `mysql_affected_rows` (as already said).

Comment: thanks for pointing out the corresponding method for Prepared Statements!

Comment: **Warning** This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0 [reference](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php#function.mysql-affected-rows-refsynopsisdiv)

Answer (score 5):

You needs [**mysql_affected_rows**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

Comment: thanks, but even then i get this error: Warning: mysql_affected_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource

Comment: You need to supply `mysql_affected_rows` with the connection identifier, not the result record, as written on http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Comment: **Warning** This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0 [reference](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php#function.mysql-affected-rows-refsynopsisdiv)

Answer (score 5):

You also may want to use a [ROW_COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) function, e.g. -

```
UPDATE table1 SET column1 = 100 WHERE column2 = 10;
SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

From the reference - ROW_COUNT()  returns the number of rows changed, deleted, or inserted by the last statement if it was an UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT...

Answer (score 3):

clamp,

you need to supply a **resource** to `mysql_affected_rows`, not a result record. See the links that the others have posted for additional information.

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
$result = mysql_query($q);
echo mysql_affected_rows($link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whe can also do it using PDO :

```
$db = new PDO('', '', '')// your connection
$sql = "UPDATE tb_table SET rowname = value WHERE rowid = 1";
$query = $db->query($sql);
echo $query;
```

Comment: $sql must be replaced by your own request