# How to get affected rows after update statement in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

How to get affected rows (not just the number of rows affected) after update statement in mysql.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP/mysql get number of affected rows of UPDATE statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356845/php-mysql-get-number-of-affected-rows-of-update-statement)

Comment: are you asking for numbers of affected rows or data of affected rows?

Comment: A simple site search / google would have given the right answer probably. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+number+of+rows+updated+php  http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&q=mysql+number+of+rows+updated+php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mysql_info — Get information about the most recent query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-info.php)

```
$recent = mysql_info();
```

Useful implementation [Example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-info.php#36008)

Comment: **Warning:** This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Use [mysqli_info()](http://www.php.net/mysqli_info) instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the actual rows and not the amount of [affected rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php), simply fetch them before doing the update.

Afterwards you can compare update values with selected values and filter them by difference.

**Example with CodeIgniter:**

```
$arr_where = array('date >=' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

$query = $this->db->get_where('table', $arr_where);

$arr_update = array('status' => 'TRUE');

if ($this->db->update('table', $arr_update, $arr_where)) {

    foreach($query->result() as $row)
        foreach(array_keys($arr_update) as $h)
            if ($row->$h != $arr_update[$h])
                echo "This row ({$row->id}) had it's {$h} changed!<br />";

}
```

Sorry for supplying solution in CodeIgniter, but I found it to be the simpliest example.

To see what the `$this->db` functions do, see [Active Records](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html).

Comment: Or fetch the id of the last modified row via mysql_insert_id(). Although I'm not sure it works on UPDATE...

Comment: You can use php to compare this. Watch above example.

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary Well it would work on a INSERT ... UPDATE. But only if one row alone is updated. However it would return regardless of success or not, thus making it pointless.

Comment: @Robin Castlin according to manual in php it says that when an auto incremented id is generated then it return value of that it.

Comment: [See this comment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html#c8755). It works as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using:

```
SET @uids := '';
UPDATE <table>
 SET <column1> = <value>
 WHERE <column2> = <value> 
   AND ( SELECT @uids := CONCAT_WS(',', @uids, id) );
SELECT TRIM(LEADING ',' FROM @uids);
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you  are using php you can use [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) to get the number of affected rows.

Comment: "Get number of affected rows in previous MySQL operation." I thought Amit wanted the rows, not just the count.

Comment: Thanks nischayn22 , but I need that field's name and their value. Is it possible to get that ? Gustav is right.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, but you can try what @Robin suggested. Be careful you don't make too many queries though (performance).

Comment: My solution could be executed through 2 queries :)